# Application to reverse engineer MySQL & PostgreSQL DB?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, reverse-engineering

Is there an application to reverse engineer an existing database in mysql and/or postgre?

I'm interested in obtaining the DB diagram from an existing one, similar as it can be done in MSSQL Server

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099444/generate-er-diagram-from-existing-postgresql-database

Answer (score 7):

For MySQL, try [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/workbench/).

For both MySQL and PostgreSQL, try [TOAD Data Modeler](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-data-modeler).

If you use the open-source diagram app [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia), there are [several tools](http://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/Links) to generate Dia diagrams from SQL databases including MySQL and PostgreSQL.

---

**update:**  MySQL Workbench 5.2 supports reverse-engineering diagrams from a live database in addition to an SQL script.  MySQL Workbench 5.2 just [announced](http://wb.mysql.com/?p=569) their Release Candidate 1 (as of 5/12/2010).

Comment: Do you need a plugin to get MySQL Workbench reverse engineer working? Where can I get it?

Comment: MySQL Workbench 5.1 is in beta now and it seems reverse engineering works only on a SQL script in the current version.  I don't know if or when a plugin will be available.

Comment: Thanks, I had MySQL Workbench already but the reverse engineering works as you say from a CREATE DATABASE SQL script. You should check out DBVisualizer.

Answer (score 5):

[SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) is a very good option for reverse engineering. For diagramming bit it uses another tool [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).
For everything to work together make sure GraphViz is installed and its path to its bin is accessible to the SchemaSpy.

Here is a [sample output](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/sample/).

Answer (score 2):

[Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html)

> Reverse engineer from many popular
>   DBMS systems, including Oracle 9i and
>   10g, SQL Server, My SQL, Access,
>   PostgreSQL and others

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/): multi-platform, free, open source, connects to most popular DB engines and supports reverse engineering.

I have tried reverse engineering both a MySQL DB and a PostgreSQL DB and it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

pgDesigner for postgres, mysql workbench for mysql...