# possibility to get structure of data base hierarchical

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to know or get whole database structure in a hierarchical format, So that I can know which table is connected to which table and all key constraints.

Comment: Have a look at [Application to reverse engineer MySQL & PostgreSQL DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/670450) (which is what you are looking for).

Comment: Thank you so much. Using DBever we can reverse engineer data base